# Qt play video store in QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qmediaplayer

When i try to play video stored in SQlite db, it not play, its work for audio,
this is the code:

```
qry.exec("select * from myTable");

    QByteArray *outByteArray;

    while (qry.next())
        outByteArray = new QByteArray(qry.value("myCol").toByteArray());

    QBuffer *mediaStream = new QBuffer(outByteArray);
    mediaStream->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget(this);
    videoWidget->setGeometry(32, 136, 400, 300);
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    player->setMedia(QMediaContent(),mediaStream);
    player->setVolume(50);
    player->play();
```

Comment: You're storing a _video_ in a SQLite table? Can I ask why?

Comment: because i dont know how to use other databases yet, i found sqlite is easy.

Comment: @MrEricSir SQLite offers a reasonable way to store named blobs. It's no different in that respect than e.g. using [COM Structured Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage), except that it is portable and you get an SQL database thrown in there for cheap :) If you're facing a choice between rolling your own and using SQLite, the latter wins almost every time.